# Plot data from a row using column name as x axis in bokeh

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bokeh

I'm starting on a project where I want to create an interactive plot from this dataset:

[image: this dataset]

For now I'm just trying to plot the first row from  the 2000 to 2012 columns, for that I use this :

```py
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.plotting import show

output_file('test.html')

df = pd.read_csv('Swedish_Population_Statistics.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
df.dropna(inplace=True)  # Drop rows with missing attributes
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)  # Remove duplicates

# Drop all the column I don't use for now
df.drop(['region', 'marital_status', 'sex'], inplace=True, axis=1)

x = df.loc[[0]]

print(x)
```

Which gives me this dataframe

|  | 2000 | 2001 | 2002 | 2003 | 2004 | 2005 | 2006 | 2007 | 2008 | 2009 | 2010 | 2011 | 2012 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10406 | 10362 | 10322 | 10288 | 10336 | 10336 | 10429 | 10585 | 10608 | 10718 | 10860 | 11121 | 11288 |

Now I want to take the column names as x-axis and the row values as y-axis.

This is where I'm stuck.

I figure the code would look like this but can't figure what to put in x and y

```py
x = df.columns.tolist() #Take columns names into a list
y = df.loc[[0]].values.tolist() # Take the first row
source = ColumnDataSource(x, y)

p = figure(title="Test")
p.line(x='x', y='y', source=source, line_color="blue", line_width=2)
```

I get this error :

> BokehUserWarning: ColumnDataSource's columns must be of the same
> length. Current lengths: ('x', 13), ('y', 1)

I don't understand why the lengths are not the same as I used `tolist()` on both.

Any help would be very appreciated, I've been trying to find a solution for the past 3 hours with no success.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include any relevant information [as text directly into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), do not link or embed external images of source code or data. Images make it difficult to efficiently assist you as they cannot be copied and offer poor usability as they cannot be searched. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888)

Comment: If you need assistance formatting a small sample of your DataFrame as a copyable piece of code for SO see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15497888).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found my problem, the main thing was that `y` was a 2-dimensional list but I needed a 1-d list.
Which leads me to this this working code :

```py
output_file('test.html')

df = pd.read_csv('Swedish_Population_Statistics.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
df.dropna(inplace=True)  # Drop rows with missing attributes
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)  # Remove duplicates

# Drop all the column I don't use for now
df.drop(['region', 'marital_status', 'sex'], inplace=True, axis=1)

x = df.columns.tolist()
y = df.loc[[0]]
temp = []
temp2 = []

# Append each value of the dataframe row in a 1-dimension list one by one

for i in range(13):
    temp.append(y[str(2000+i)].tolist())
    temp2.append(temp[i][0])

p = figure(title="Test", sizing_mode="scale_both")
p.line(x, temp2, line_color="blue", line_width=2)
p.circle(x, temp2, fill_color="white", size=8)

show(p)
```

With this result :

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yL5VY.png)

Answer (score 0):

no need to create a loop. You were on the right track but you should not use double brackets

```
>>> df.loc[0].values.tolist()
[111, 222, 333]
```

Then the dimensions of `x` and `y` are the same.